# Bulk Un-checking

Tags: import

I wanted to know if there is a way to un-check a section in individual contacts in a bulk size way rather than going into each individual contact and un-checking the section i need un-checked.

Answer (score 1):

You can create profile with the fields you want to updated and then use bulk update action from search action to update multiple records.

Doc: https://www.cividesk.com/blog/post/batch-update-using-profiles

Thanks

Pradeep